# Django - Select2 Lookup no ajax request

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 to do ajax lookups within my app. On the form template I have the following code:

```
<input class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" id="id_tag_fk" name="tag_fk" placeholder="Tag fk" required="true" type="text" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#id_tag_fk').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "http://localhost:8000/taglookup",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: "one", // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection

});
    function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

    var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
    '<img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" style="max-width: 100%" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
    '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    if (repo.description) {
      markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
    }

    markup += '</div></div>';

    return markup;
  }

    function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
  }
```

Then I have my urls.py:

```
url(r'^taglookup/$', views.tag_lookup, name='tag-lookup'),
```

and my views.py:

```
def tag_lookup(request):
    print "IN HERE HERE"
    # do something with the your data
    data = {'items':['a','b','c']}

    # just return a JsonResponse
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I do not get any terminal errors, or any console errors, but I dont get any prints in the terminal, and also it looks like there are no requests going out from the browser DevConsole-Network tab. 
The select2 searchfield just shows: no resutls found.

I cannot see why this is not working, any suggestions?

**Update**

The following ajax call is working after some CSP changes..

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"/taglookup",
    data: {
    'zip': 'twwas',
    },
    success: function(data){            
        alert("SUCCESS")

    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Error");
    },
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your Html markup i.e. html of this item - `$('#id_tag_fk')`

Comment: I have added it. This is the generated input, the original is created by a django form.

Comment: If you initialize Select2 with `debug: true`, does your console show anything new?

Comment: Nothing... also I added code from this gist: https://gist.github.com/chrishough/f4870fe9124d5243a485#file-select2-debug-L10 ... nothing outputted on the console... so something must be broken on my system.. Even though the dropdown with 'No results' shows there is no console out.

Comment: I  got the feeling its going to be one of those silly things, causing the rolleye effect..

Comment: Plain ajax is working... select2 not yet..